# linking error during compiling

Tags: ios, frameworks

I got this error:

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NKLocalJSONParser", referenced from: objc-class-ref in 
BBCNepaliNews.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: 
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) "
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try shift + command + k and then try building it again.  This will clean your build.  Alternatively, if this is an open api, make sure that when you imported the files into your project that you made sure to set the target as your project and that you copied them in rather than just putting references to them.